# Send android event from php

Tags: php, android, android-event

I'm trying to create intranet PHP application that communicates with android phones.
So I was wondering is it possible to trigger android event from PHP and I don't need push messages.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In general no, unless you implement push messaging (with GCM). What you can do is have a polling mechanism in the app to check the server for new content.